# How to prevent \url from removing the spaces in a path?

Tags: hyperref, urls

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{"a b c.tex"}
one
two
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[caption={\url{a b c.tex}}]{"a b c.tex"}
\end{document}
```

produces a hyperlink with suppressed spaces given in the path.

How to prevent `\url` from removing the spaces in a path?

Comment: I'd encode the spaces anyway, as `%20`. It's annoying, and ugly, but clearer for someone who may be copying your URL, as users do not expect URLs to contain spaces.

Comment: Are you not happy with the answer you received to this question? It's usually a good idea to specify what's missing from existing answers when offering a bounty on a question, so people know how they can help you better.

Comment: @Jake: I am very happy with the existing answer.

Comment: @AdorableCreature: That's great! Why do you feel that this question has not received enough attention, then?

Comment: @Jake: Because I want to let other people who read [How do you put spaces in \url?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88944/19356) know this related question and to get more upvotes.

Comment: @AdorableCreature: Ah, okay. A better/cheaper way to emphasise the relation between the two questions might be to post a link to this question as a comment on the other question, which will create an entry in the "Linked" list on the right-hand side. Also, you could vote to close as a duplicate, which (if successful) creates a very prominent link at the top of the other question.

Comment: @Jake: Implicitly mentioned mission is [The top investors](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/65683/top-investors). :-)

Comment: URL (or URI, URN...) can't contain space character: it's an unsafe character! A space must be encoded (`%20`). See [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).

Comment: @PaulGaborit That same document says that ~ is unsafe, but it's common to write URLs with the ~ symbol (not encoded).

Comment: @AriBrodsky Common errors do not contradict the rule...

Comment: `\nolinkurl` instead of `\url` can be used to avoid the non-functional Link because of the invalid URL.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Add the following load order to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

See the TeX FAQ entry [Typesetting URLs](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-setURL). Or, since [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) loads [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) by default, perhaps with other package options, use:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}% ~ \usepackage[...,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
```

See [Option clash for package](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-optionclash), also from the TeX FAQ.

[image]

Comment: When I click the link, the browser fails to load the file because of additional `25` inserted between `%` and `20`. Please see [these screenshots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N0jQ7.png).

Comment: @GarbageCollector: I'm having no such problems, even when setting Google Chrome to my default application to open `.tex` files. The file opens as expected.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have to try the earlier version of Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Werner's answer I found the following was necessary in the preamble ...

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}

% Other packages which might use the url package.

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

That is, in practice one needs to use `\PassOptionsToPackage` just after the package you want to protect, rather than just before the conflicting package you suspect is causing the problem (in this example: hyperref). In other words, I had to move ....

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}
```

... toward the top of my preamble, keeping `\usepackage{hyperref}` toward the bottom, in order to handle other packages that might be calling `url` or `hyperref`

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage` *after* the package is already loaded, does not make much sense. `hyperref` loads package `url` without any option. Either the package `url` is loaded before with the option: `\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}`. Or `\PassOptionsToPackage` *before* loading of `url` and `hyperref` can be used: `\PassOptionsToPackage{obeyspaces}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}`.