# How to type blank in URL for a path

Tags: urls

Say I have to add a file path like "\F\A B\C". Please note the blank between A and B are intended. I tried this as below. However, the blank is missing. How to fix it, please? Usually \ plus a blank means a blank. Right?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\url{\\\\F\\A\ B\\C}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `url` package option `obeyspaces`:

```
\documentclass[obeyspaces]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\url{\\\\F\\A B\\C}

\end{document}
```

But I think your question is a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76554/101651).

Comment: Thanks. I shall delete my question shortly. However, I would not be able to accept your answer then. Sorry.

Comment: @LaTeXFan you don't need to delete your question. It   could remain, marked as duplicate.